# Java syntax - extra plus sign after cast is valid?

Tags: java, syntax, casting

So I came across something that confused me when casting a `byte` to `char`, usually I would do this:

```
for (byte b:"ABCDE".getBytes()) {
    System.out.println((char)b);
}
```

Which will print out

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

I accidentally left a `+` between the `(char)` and `b` and got the **same** result!?

Like so:

```
for (byte b:"ABCDE".getBytes()) {
    System.out.println((char) + b);
}
```

**Why exactly is this happening?**

Am I essentially doing `(char)(0x00 + b)`? Because

```
System.out.println((char) - b);
```

yields a different result.

Note: Using Java version 1.8.0_20

Comment: By directly casting bytes to chars, you are ignoring [character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Why exactly is this happening?

If you put a unary `-` operator before a number or expression it negates it.

Similarly, if you put a unary `+` operator before a number or expression it does nothing.

A safer way to convert a byte to a char is

```
char ch = (char)(b & 0xFF);
```

This will work for characters between 0 and 255, rather than 0 to 127.

BTW you can use unary operators to write some confusing code like

```
int i = (int) + (long) - (char) + (byte) 1; // i = -1;
```

Comment: If the intention is the convert a binary encoded text string to characters, there's actually no safe way just to cast the bytes to chars. You have to use any of the several methods in the API, which consider the character encoding (String constructors, Reader, CharsetDecoder, etc.).

Comment: @jarnbjo +1 Unless you can assume US-ASCII or ISO-8859-1 encoding (which the example above do), you have to use an encoder.  You can write a UTF-8 encoder yourself if you are really keen, but one of the builtin encoders is likely to be the best choice.

Answer (score 7):

b is a byte, and that be expressed as + b as well. For example, 3 can be written as +3 as well. So, ((char) + b) is same as ((char) b)

Answer (score 5):

The `+` is the unary plus operator - like you can say that `1` is equivalent to `+1`, `b` is equivalent to `+b`. The space between `+` and `b` is inconsequential. This operator has a higher precedence than the cast, so after it's applied (doing nothing, as noted), the resulting `byte` is then cast to a `char` and produces the same result as before.